# move specific files to different subfolders matching a character

Tags: bash

I have a list of files ~100,000 txt files with the following pattern name: `file_[combination of letters and numbers]_[numbers from 1 to 400].txt`, three examples would be:

`file_ab34_1.txt`, `file_ab35_1.txt`, `file_bg12_2.txt`, `file_bg12_2.txt`. What I want to do automatically is move all the files with `_1` to a subfolder named `/1` and all the files with `_2` to a subfolder `/2` and so on.

I would need a bash script to do it automatically and not one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please back up your files before trying this answer.

I would try `rename`, like this:

```
rename --dry-run 's|(.*)_(\d+).txt|$2/$1_$2.txt|' *.txt
'file_ab34_1.txt' would be renamed to '1/file_ab34_1.txt'
'file_ab35_1.txt' would be renamed to '1/file_ab35_1.txt'
'file_bg12_2.txt' would be renamed to '2/file_bg12_2.txt'
```

The `--dry-run` just shows you what it would do without actually doing anything - great for testing before using.

It is basically Perl, and it is doing a substitution on the filename. The bones of it is to substitute like this:

```
s|something|something else|
```

Every time there are parentheses on the left side (called `capture groups`), they capture some aspect of the left side and it is then available as a numbered item to put in the replacement, right hand side, where `$1` represents whatever was captured in the first set of parentheses and `$2` represents whatever was in the second set of parentheses and so on.

You will likely need `-p` option to create the output directories, so:

```
rename -p ....
```

If you get errors about the argument list being too long, you will probably need to use `find` and `xargs`, along these lines (untested):

```
find . -name \*.txt -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1000 rename ....
```

Comment: any solution @MarkSetchell if I get the `/usr/bin/rename: Argument list too long` error...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with just `mv` with shell globbing to get the files:

```
mv -t /1 file_*_1.txt
mv -t /2 file_*_2.txt
```